# How can I get emacs to display a stop-sign icon when I set a breakpoint?

Tags: matlab, emacs

I'm running emacs 23.4 on OSX, obtained from emacsformacosx.com. I'm writing matlab code, using the latest code from matlab-emacs.sourceforge.net. This mode includes integration with GUD for stepping through matlab code.

I can set breakpoints and step through matlab code with no problems. However, when I set breakpoints, no "stop-sign" icon appears next to the lines that have breakpoints. The arrow icon indicating the line on which you are stopped *does* appear.

I've seen emacs screenshots online that show stop-sign icons, but I can't find any GUD documentation on this.

How can I get these icons to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic GUD mode does not support this. Recent versions of Emacs has  a special gdb mode which uses the gdb machine interface and therefore can show breakpoints. I think the matlab debugger is based on GUD.

Comment: I got the same answer from the matlab-emacs mailing list. There are some more details there: [How can I get emacs to display a stop-sign icon when I set a breakpoint?](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAFuXnicqWY_3kGPX%3DDqCTc_8F%2BG3tsrs5EV2HDoFryM3rEcN_g%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=matlab-emacs-discuss)